# C switch, how to fix multiple default prints?

Tags: c, char, switch-statement, scanf, getchar

If i give my program this:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

It answered with this?!

```
Invalid command a
Invalid command c
Invalid command e
Invalid command g
Invalid command i
Invalid command k
Invalid command m
Invalid command o
Invalid command q
Invalid command s
Invalid command u
Invalid command w
Invalid command y
```

Any idea why only every other letter is getting my default message, and why there is so many and not just one, how can i fix this so i only get one default message no matter how many invalid characters i input?

Here is that part of my code:

```
while (1) {
  scanf("%c", &command);
  getchar();

  switch (command) {
  case 'A': // Adds a new entry to the program database.
    if (scanf("%s %f", name, &price) != 2) {
      printf("A should be followed by exactly 2 arguments.\n");
      // while (getchar() != '\n'); // Clear the input buffer
    } else {
      getchar(); // Consume the newline character
      addGame(&games, &numGames, name, price); // Pass pointer to games
    }
    break;
  case 'B': // Buy game command, which sells a specified number of games
    if (scanf("%s %d", name, &count) != 2 || count <= 0) {
      getchar(); // Consume the newline character
      printf("Number of bought items cannot be less than 1.\n");
    } else {
      getchar(); // Consume the newline character
      buyGame(games, numGames, name, count);
    }
    break;
  case 'L': //Prints a list of the program database into the standard output
    printDatabase(games, numGames);
    break;
  case 'W': //Writes the program database into a text file
    scanf("%s", filename);
    getchar();
    saveToFile(games, numGames, filename);
    break;
  case 'O': //Loads the database from the specified text file
    scanf("%s", filename);
    getchar();
    loadFromFile(&games, &numGames, filename); // Pass pointer
    break;
  case 'Q': //Quits the program after releasing the program database
    releaseMemory(games, numGames);
    return 0;
  case '\n': //Not sure i need this?
    break;
  default:
    printf("Invalid command %c\n", command);
  }
}
```

I can send more of my code if someone think it's needed :)

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &command);` Put a space before `%c` to skip leading whitespace. That may help. [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: Please indent your code, it will make it easier to read and understand what it does.

Comment: And the whole "consume the newline character" business is not needed. See the comment by @RetiredNinja for a simple way to remove all those `getchar()` calls. Note, that leading space in the format is *only* needed by `%c` (and `%[`), not for any other format which does it automatically.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `%n` also doesn’t consume white space, but it is something of an oddball conversion specification.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers :) Answer to "Please indent your code" I tried to paste my code how it should be, but the "add your question" page didn't let me post until i rap*d it like that x)

Comment: I tried that " Put a space before %c" but it messed things up with cases that has arguments

Comment: Speaking of indentation: that's rather for _you_ than for us. Unindented code is hard to work with and even harder for beginners.

Comment: You inputed lowercases while uppercases are waited. try `ABCDE...`

Comment: @RonjaOksanen then edit the code by hand.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of the while loop you have

```
while (1) {
scanf("%c", &command);
getchar()
//...
```

So when you enter such a sequence of symbols

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

then the call of scanf reads one character as for example 'a' and the next call of getchar reads the next character 'b'. As the command 'a' is invalid then next call of scanf reads the next character 'c' and the call of getchar reads the letter 'd' and so on. What you do is what you get.

Instead of these two calls

```
scanf("%c", &command);
getchar()
```

you could use only one call of `scanf`  like

```
scanf(" %c", &command);
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters including the new line character `'\n'`. And if the input is invalid you should clear the input buffer under the label `default` for example like

```
while ( getchar() != '\n' );
```

or

```
scanf( "%*[^\n]" );
```

And remove calls of `getchar` also in other places of your code.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I think this will fix my problem :) I just started C language like 2 months ago so I'm really bad at this and i was sure everyone here would just laugh at me ^^

Answer (score 0):

You read only *one* character at a time, not whole lines. That's why you get "so many and not just one".

To read whole lines use `fgets` instead. And add validation that only one character was input, if you need.

The reason you only get every second character reported as wrong, is just because of the misguided `getchar` call after `scanf("%c", &command)`. The `scanf` call will read e.g. `a`, then the `getchar` call will read the `b`. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

in your loop, at the top:

```
  scanf("%c", &command);  /* read one char into command */
  getchar();              /* skip the next char, ignoring it */
```

you read a character into `command`, then `getchar()` just drops the next char.  This is why you read alternate characters and produce that output, as the input characters are lowercase while you are checking only for some uppercase characters.